# Practical Resources for the Amateur Radio Student?

Tags: license, electronics, education

What electrical circuits can be easily build by someone with basic electrical engineering skills that exemplify the fundamental components of radios, antennas and so on?

Comment: Can the "put on hold" status be removed please since the question is more specific now?

Comment: Questions should have, in principle, one best answer. This question is open-ended will tend to have everyone proposing their favorites (their own definition of “easy” and “exemplifies …”) and no basis for ranking the answers.

Comment: So? That is actually what I want. Don't mind if I get lots of different answers.  My goal is to get at least ONE! As it is often in life, there is not only ONE best solution and answers are mostly subjective. If applying your proposed measures there won't hardly be any answers out there to anything ... Just think about answering like that to a child asking you about something she has no idea about. Anyways, never mind, you set the rules.

Comment: I actually think the question as edited (disclaimer: it was my edit) is fairly answerable.  I'm not an electronics expert, but it seems that most of us here could agree on a few basic circuits that would help people learn some radio basics.  And in this particular case, a "well-cited" answer would be one with useful links to projects, descriptions, etc.